# the procedure entry point SHGetKnownFolderPath shell32 not located

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, windows-xp, windows-10

I'm using visual studio 2013 and compile something to run it on windows XP. It runs fine on my windows 10 machine but when i start under XP i get the error:

```
the procedure entry point "SHGetKnownFolderPath" could not be located in the dynamic link library shell32.dll
```

The options in my vs-project are set to XP variant (v120_XP). I also tried to set _WIN32_WINNT (and other defines i found on the internet) to XP define variants (e.g. _WIN32_WINNT=0x0501) without success.

I'm using some libraries which are all compiled unsing v120_XP (e.g boost).

Any advice is welcome to get my project running on windows xp.

### UPDATE:

Sorry my fault. Even all libraries were forced not to use anything what is not provided by XP i missed one library which was not compiled by myself is using `SHGetKnownFolderPath`. I found it by dumpbin-ing all libraries. it was SimConnect.lib, used for Prepar3D. Later i found:

> Prepar3D v2 is not 
>   compatible with Windows XP and is not recommended on Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3):

`SHGetKnownFolderPath` does not exist in XP, it's only available in Vista and above.

Comment: That's right but why do i get the error if everything is compiler in XP mode?

Comment: If your code uses a function that doesn't exist on XP, then it won't run on XP.  Setting the compiler to XP mode won't change that.

Comment: How will it fail? on startup? or on function call?

Comment: @A.Smoliak The program will refuse to run, with an ugly dialog complaining about a missing DLL entry point.

Comment: Might be a good addition to the answer itself then, because this means if you wish to write backwards compatible code might need to either not compile it or dynamically link if available.. I just had this damn scenario..